# Neo4J - How to merge nodes with the same attribute value (name) but different node labels

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher

I currently have duplicate name values across different node labels and I want to merge them. The issue is that every question I've found online assumes that BOTH the attribute name and the labels are the same. The code I've executed to query the instances I'm referring to is:

```sql
MATCH (a)-[r:FEATURED_IN]->(b) WHERE a.name = b.name AND id(a) <> id(b)
```

So that means that 'a' is featured in 'b', obviously 'a' and 'b' refer to the different node labels but the values are the same. How can I perform a merge to ensure that the 'b' node is deleted and only the 'a' node is returned? I know I could do this manually but there are so many instances of this that I would like to find a quick fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give us an example data to work with. Thanks.

Comment: For example, CREATE (n:Node1 {name: "1"})-[r:SYN_OF]->(n2:Node2 {name: "Same Name"})-[r2:SYN_OF]->(n3:Node3 {name: "Same Name"})-[r3:SYN_OF]->(n4:Node4 {name: "4"}). I want to merge Nodes 2 and 3 such that the relationship between "4" and "Same Name" is maintained except there is only one "Same Name" of label Node2 (the lowest possible level), while Node3 is removed and the relationship between Node4 and Node3 is now between Node4 and Node2. I want to be able to do this for every instance where there are multiple cases of the same attribute name in the pathway albeit with different labels.

Comment: please tell me what you want to return. is it name only?

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all names in the nodes and combine them. Then UNWIND (it is like a For loop) and return distinct name.

```
MATCH (a)-[r:SYN_OF]->(b) WHERE a.name = b.name AND id(a) <> id(b)
WITH collect(distinct a.name) + collect(distinct b.name) as names
UNWIND names as name
RETURN distinct name
```

Result:

```
╒═══════════╕
│"name"     │
╞═══════════╡
│"Same Name"│
└───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This provides me with a list of names but how do I combine the nodes for each of the names for which there are multiple nodes with the same name? Sorry I am quite new to Neo4J/Cypher.